# How to convert column names to multi-index of row

Tags: python, pandas

I have statistical data about two attributes for multiple years. Each year's data is a separated .csv file. I am trying to combine these files to one so that I can do time series analysis. Therefore, the result the I want to get is a data frame which has years as a row index and multi-indexed column with two attributes.

However, in order to make multi-index, the two attributes should be in the same axis, but the attributes in the original data aren't like that; they are consisting of two different axes.

To simplify, the original data look like below.

### | |A|B|

### |a||1|2|

### |b||3|4|

how can I make it like below?
The first two row is multi-indexed columns.

### | ||A      |B      |

### | ||a|b|a|b|

### |0||1|3|2|4|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pandas.DataFrame.unstack`:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(df.unstack()).T
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
   A     B   
   a  b  a  b
0  1  3  2  4
```